# Confusion about a conditional probability question?

Tags: probability

> Music and Math are said to be two subjects that are closely related in
>   the way the students think as they learn. At the local high school,
>   the probability that a student takes math and music is 0.25. The
>   probability that a student is taking math is 0.85. What is the
>   probability that a student that is in music is also choosing math?

Here I am not able to undersatnd what probability, Do I have to calculate?

Do I have to calculate **P(Math|Music) or P(Music|Math)?**

Accoding to the last line of this question-

> What is the
>   probability that a student that is in music is also choosing math?

Please correct me if I am wrong- **It means a studen is already in music and I have to calculate P(Math) given that a stduent is already in music.**

But when I checked the answer it is other way around. Please help me to figure out.

Comment: You want $\Pr(\text{student taking math} \mid \text{student taking music})$ conventionally using a vertical bar $\mid$ rather than $/$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > What is the probability that a student that is in music is also choosing math?
>
> Please correct me if I am wrong- It means a student is already in music and I have to calculate $\rm P(Math)$ given that a student is already in music.

No, you are not wrong; if that was the question asked, then you've interpreted it correctly.   That is asking you to calculate the conditional probability that a student is taking math, given that that student is taking music.   That is: $\mathsf P({\rm Math}\mid {\rm Music})$ .

However, you have only been given $\mathsf P({\rm Math}\cap{\rm Music})=0.25$ and $\mathsf P({\rm Math})= 0.85$ .   So you can't get to there from here.

Thus the reason the book gave the answer it did would appear to be because *the book* asked the wrong question.

Comment: I was also thinking that question is wrong.